# External events to WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to run my WPF application programmatically and so am using the Application class and calling the Run method.

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Run(new MainWindow());
```

I'd now like to programmatically send events to the WPF application to simulate button clicks however am unsure of the best way to do this.

For info, my objective is to run my application from a Python script and activate some of the controls. To achieve this in WPF I convert the app to a library and make a COM component. So my COM server class has access to the Application object and I'd therefore like to therefore post button click event to the running Window.

Further EDIT: It appears the main issue is that the Run() method doesn't return until the Window closes. So the problem I have is that I'd like to call Run() to execute the application in a non blocking manner and then find a way of posting messages, or events to it.

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you may be well-served by reviewing the functionality contained in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls namespace and the rest of the UITesting world.

Comment: Thanks. I considered this but this is not what I'm looking for. I've updated my post to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

It's sounds like you've tightly coupled your app code to WPF events.  While you *could* automate that type of user interaction, I would strongly recommend de-coupling that code by putting it in a separate assembly that is independent of your UI (i.e. takes input through parameters instead of from UI controls, etc.).

That way you can automate your app code without having to go through the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting point. The model could be placed in a separate assembly. For this purpose it is advantageous to have the WPF GUI running.